# How can I send a completed activity in an email to a non SF user

Tags: email

How can I send a SF task (standard) or completed event in an email. We have contract data entry people that are not on our sf system and we log changes as activities and need to sent the activity as an email in order to get instruction to the contract department. I would like to have this as an option of "send". Please help.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange !Please add more info around this and indicate what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you really need? Actually you can send an email via Apex Code to anyone (Salesforce user or external user that is not related to Salesforce) with the information of the Task or the Event.

```
 List<String> address = new List<String>();
 address.add('myemail@ff.com');

 Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
 mail.setToAddresses( address );

 String body = 'My Email body';
 mail.setSubject( 'My Email subject');
 mail.setPlainTextBody( body );

 Messaging.sendEmail( new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail } );
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what i needed to know. Sending the body of the task via email is precisely what I need to configure a button for. I'm not a coder, but I'll try and figure out how to insert your info above and make it happen.

Comment: @Ben you can create an Apex Class and call the code from many places. A list view button, a record button, or even create a Process Builder that call this Apex class.

Comment: @Ben This blog talk about how to do it ( http://salesforceworld4u.blogspot.com.es/2015/05/how-to-call-apex-class-from-process.html ) If you aren't technical, you can also use Salesforce tools to send emails (Flow, Workflow and even Process Builder) They help u to customize an email with your Task info. ( http://thewizardnews.com/2015/04/02/process-builder-flow-email-templates-awesomeness/ ) If it works for u please, mark it as solution